# IFileDialog / IShellItem::GetDisplayName doesn't work with Windows 7 libraries

Tags: c++, winapi, com, windows-7

```
IFileDialog *pfd;
...
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog,NULL,
   CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_PPV_ARGS(&pfd));
...
IShellItem *psiResult;
pfd->GetResult(&psiResult);
...
wchar_t *filepath;
psiResult->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH,&filepath);
...
```

This works perfectly well for regular files but fails (E_INVALIDARG) when the file is fetched via a Windows 7 library folder (the same file will work when accessed via it's normal path). The [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762544%28VS.85%29.aspxE) says that :

> SIGDN_FILESYSPATH (Returns the item's
>   file system path, if it has one. Only
>   items that report SFGAO_FILESYSTEM
>   have a file system path. **When an item
>   does not have a file system path, a
>   call to IShellItem::GetDisplayName on
>   that item will fail**. In UI this name
>   is suitable for display to the user in
>   some cases, but note that it might not
>   be specified for all items.

But using SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY or all others SIGDN Enumeration fails too.

So how to get full path when the file is fetched via a Windows 7 libraries ?

**EDIT 1**

I can get the folder via :

```
IShellItem *psiResult;
pfd->GetFolder(& psiResult); 
LPWSTR folderpath = NULL; 
psiResult->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, & folderpath);
```

But GetDisplayName() doesn't work with pfd->GetResult(& psiResult);

**EDIT 2**

I found what was not working, it was in CoInitializeEx. I used COINIT_MULTITHREADED, if I change it to COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED it then works.

Comment: Your first code works for me. Do you call pfd->Show() with NULL argument?

Answer (score 1):

Try calling

```
pfd->SetOptions(dwOptions | FOS_FORCEFILESYSTEM | FOS_PATHMUSTEXIST);
```

before showing the dialog. This works for me.

Comment: It was a  CoInitializ.eEx problem. Thanks anyway.